# General formula of $I_{2n} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^{2n}}dx$

Tags: integration

$I_{2n} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^{2n}}dx$

We know very well 
$I_{2}= \sqrt{\pi}$

Could you please help me find general formula of $I_{2n}$?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may rewrite $I_{2n}$ using the integral definition of the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Main_definition) :
$$\Gamma(s)= \int_0^{\infty} t^{s-1} e^{-t} dt$$

Let's set $t=x^{2n}$ then :
$$\Gamma(s)= 2n \int_0^{\infty} x^{2n(s-1)} e^{-x^{2n}} x^{2n-1}dx$$

For $s=\frac1{2n}$ the powers of $x$ disappear and we get :
$$\Gamma\left(\frac1{2n}\right)= 2n \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^{2n}} dx$$
so that (we multiply by $2$ since the integral of $I_{2n}$ starts from $-\infty$)
$$I_{2n}=2\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac1{2n}\right)}{2n}=2\Gamma\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right).$$

No closed form is known for $\Gamma(1/4)$ nor other fractions (except $\Gamma(1/2)$ of course!) as opposed to the derivatives of $(\ln(\Gamma))$ where closed forms exist for every fraction!

Some interesting equalities concerning $\Gamma(1/n)$ may be found at [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) (equation (63) and following), the reference to 
Chudnovsky's proof of the transcendence of $\Gamma(1/3)$ and $\Gamma(1/4)$ and iterative algorithms for $\Gamma(k/24)$.